# Add a line plot in stack of rasters in spplot R

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sp

I have a stack of rasters.

```
## read the libraries
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

##random raster object
r <- raster(ncol=40, nrow=20)
r[] <- rnorm(n=ncell(r))
# Create a RasterStack object with 3 layers
s <- stack(x=c(r, r*2, r**2))

##coordinate system
wgs<-CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

##plotting with spplot
plot(spplot(s,layout=c(2,2),
            colorkey =list(space = "right"),
            names.attr = c("a","b","c")))
```

[image]

So far, I have plotted the stack of raster in `layout=c(2,2)`. Now, in the empty 2nd row and 2nd column I want to plot the mean of raster stack as a line plot. Something like this....

```
plot(cellStats(s, stat='mean', na.rm=TRUE, 
     asSample=TRUE),type="l",ylab="mean",xlab="value")
```

Can anyone help me with this?

[image]